# How to open The specific Activity after clicking FCM push notification

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have tried to open the specific activity after clicking the push notification

Here is the code

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "my_notification";
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;


    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String s) {
        super.onNewToken(s);
        Log.d("Token:", s);
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        // Check if the message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
            String message = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
            Log.d("msg:", message);
            // Pass the notification data to the NotificationActivity.
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("title", title);
            intent.putExtra("message", message);
            TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
            stackBuilder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(intent);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent =
                    stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,
                            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

            // Build the notification.
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic)
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                    .setAutoCancel(true);
            builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

            int notificationId = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
            NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
            notificationManager.notify(notificationId, builder.build());
        }
    }

}
```

Here is is my Androidmanifest.xml for fcm

```
 <service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_click_action"
            android:value=".NotificationActivity" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id" />
```

Here iam facing the issue like the NotificationActivity is not opening And the onMessageRecived function is not running in background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is my code.

```
public static void sendNotification(Context context, String title, String body, 
Map<String, String> data, String userType) {
        Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), 
R.drawable.ic_my_taxi);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationActivityDriver.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "channel_id")
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setContentInfo(title)
            .setLargeIcon(icon)
            .setColor(Color.BLUE)
            .setLights(Color.BLUE, 1000, 300)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_my_icon);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

Manifest file is below

```
 <service
        
 android:name="com.notification.test.service.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:directBootAware="true"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Comment: i don't have any idea about calling this function can you please explain

Comment: Just call the function like this: 

sendNotification(activity, "title", "body", null, "user type");

Here 4th parameter, data is for detail content for showing in notification.
Simply you can set null.

Comment: Hi now the code works fine, now I have added extra method to pass the data to the activity can you please help me with this question in the link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76252977/how-to-show-the-notification-data-in-new-activity-using-firebase-and-show-the-co](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76252977/how-to-show-the-notification-data-in-new-activity-using-firebase-and-show-the-co)

Comment: I answered there. Let me know if you still have problem.

Comment: Let me try that one