# how to show the notification data in new activity using firebase and show the content in Activity

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Here is my code of notification. Actually, I'm getting the notification perfectly but when I click on the notification in a phone the app will open directly. When the app is in the foreground,the data sent from the **MyFirebaseInstanceIDService**  the **ResultActivity** will open correctly when I click on notification but the data is showing over there, But in background it is not showing the data over there.

MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.java

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "my_app";
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;


    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String s) {
        super.onNewToken(s);
        Log.d("Token:", s);
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        // Check if the a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
            String message = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
            String click = remoteMessage.getNotification().getClickAction();
            Log.d("msg:", message);
            sendNotification(this,title,message,click);
        }
    }

    public static void sendNotification(Context context, String title, String body,String action)  {
        Intent intent = new Intent(action);
        intent.putExtra("title",title);
        intent.putExtra("message",body);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                context,
                0,
                intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT |
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

        Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setContentInfo(title)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic)
                .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
                .setAutoCancel(true);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build());
    }

}
```

NotificationActivity.java

```
public class NotificationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "NotificationActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_notification);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    TextView titleTextView = findViewById(R.id.title_text_view);
    TextView messageTextView = findViewById(R.id.message_text_view);

    String title = intent.getStringExtra("title");
    String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
    Log.d(TAG, "Received notification: " + title + " - " + message);

    // Update the UI with the notification data
    titleTextView.setText(title);
    messageTextView.setText(message);
}}
```

Please check my code and let me know what I did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

sendNotification function seems to be wrong.

```
sendNotification(Context context, String title, String body,String action)
```

Remove 4th param and change the code as below.

```
public static void sendNotification(Context context, String title, String body)  {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ResultActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("title",title);
    intent.putExtra("message",body);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            context,
            0,
            intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT |
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
    ...
}
```

Please refer this link:
https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/navigation